# How do I replace multiple different parts of a string at once?

Tags: javascript

So, I have a string that is a series of numbers that range from 1-6. Depending on the number in question, I want to replace each with a different piece of code. This is for a Discord bot, so each of the six numbers should be replaced by a different Discord emoji code. I've tried using string.replace chains but, as these emoji codes contain numbers, the replacements start stacking on top of each other and replacing the replacements (That's a mouthful, I know!) which totally bugs out the code.

Here's an example chain:

```
1 2 1 4 6
```

And this is an index for how the numbers should be replaced:

```
1 = <:attr1:710526292784578581>
2 = <:attr2:710526292721664142>
3 = <:attr3:710526292642103398>
etc.
```

So it should turn out a string like this ideally, not one that ends up jumbled and mixed because the replacement chain is eating itself alive.

```
<:attr1:710526292784578581> <:attr2:710526292721664142> <:attr3:710526292642103398>
```

How can I make these replacements essentially all at once so that they *only* affect the items in the string, and don't start affecting each other? Answers would be much appreciated!

Edit: This was my own attempt with the replace chains which returns a buggy mess.

```
var attribEmoji = attribResult.join(" ").replace(/1/g, "<:attr1:710526292784578581>").replace(/2/g, "<:attr2:710526292721664142>").replace(/3/g, "<:attr3:710526292642103398>");
```

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: I have added the attempt I've already made, I thought my initial description of the replacement chain would have proved sufficient. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback argument of `replace`:

```js
// Define the replacements as key/value pairs:
let map = {
    "1": "<:attr1:710526292784578581>",
    "2": "<:attr2:710526292721664142>",
    "3": "<:attr3:710526292642103398>",
    // add as needed...
};

// Create a regular expression from the keys:
let regex = new RegExp(`[${Object.keys(map).join("")}]`, "g");

// sample input
let attribResult = [1,2,1,3];

// Perform the substitutions
var attribEmoji = attribResult.join(" ").replace(regex, m => map[m]);

console.log(attribEmoji);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this:

```js
str = '1 2 1 4 6';
replacement = {
'1': '<:attr1:710526292784578581>',
'2': '<:attr2:710526292721664142>',
'3': '<:attr3:710526292642103398>',
'4': '<:attr4:710526292642103772>',
'5': '<:attr5:710526292642103008>',
'6': '<:attr6:710526292642105566>'
}
newStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newStr += replacement[str.charAt(i)] ? replacement[str.charAt(i)] : str.charAt(i)
}

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the numerical chain, if every number has a space after it and the replacement numbers don't, then that is a simple problem to solve. Create an array of your icons and loop through them replacing the index with a space with the proper code.

```js
var emojis = [];
emojis[1] = "<:attr1:710526292784578581>";
emojis[2] = "<:attr2:710526292721664142>";
emojis[3] = "<:attr3:710526292642103398>";
var chain = "1 2 3 ";

emojis.forEach(function(i,v){
chain = chain.replace(v + " ",i + " ");
});

console.log(chain);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const replaceMultiple = input => {
  const mapping = {
    '1': '<:attr1:710526292784578581>',
    '2': '<:attr2:710526292721664142>',
    '3': '<:attr3:710526292642103398>',
  }

  return input
    .split(' ')
    .map(inputNum => mapping[inputNum])
    .join(' ')
}
```

Usage

```
replaceMultiple('1 3 2')
// '<:attr1:710526292784578581> <:attr3:710526292642103398> <:attr2:710526292721664142>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the related values and replament values and search for a number and replace with the value from the object.

```js
var replacements = {
        1: '<:attr1:710526292784578581>',
        2: '<:attr2:710526292721664142>',
        3: '<:attr3:710526292642103398>',
        4: '<:attr4:710526292642103398>',
        5: '<:attr5:710526292642103398>',
        6: '<:attr6:710526292642103398>'
    },
    string = '1 2 1 4 6',
    replaced = string.replace(/[1-6]/g, v => replacements[v]);

console.log(replaced);
```